# Weblogic WsdlcTask for gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy, ant, weblogic, wsdlc

I am looking for the `weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.WsdlcTask` for gradle. All I could find so far was an example for [Ant](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/webserv/anttasks.html#1047066).

Importing the ant script with `ant.importBuild "wsdlc_build.xml"` works perfectly fine in my gradle build script, but I would prefer writing the task in gradle. Has someone already found a solution for this?

My ant script:

```
<project name="WebServices" basedir=".">

<property name="build.wls.home" value="C:\User\wls\"/>

<path id="weblogic.tools.path">
    <fileset dir="${build.wls.home}/wlserver/server/lib">
        <include name="weblogic.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>
<taskdef name="wsdlc" classname="weblogic.wsee.tools.anttasks.WsdlcTask" classpathref="weblogic.tools.path"/>

<target name="build_opera">
    <wsdlc failOnError="true" 
        srcWsdl="WebContent/WEB-INF/wsdls/OperaService.wsdl" 
        destImplDir="src" 
        destJwsDir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" 
        packageName="server.opera.webservice.service" 
        verbose="on" debug="on"
        type="JAXWS">
    </wsdlc>

</target>

<target name="build_nez">
    <wsdlc
        failOnError="true"
        srcWsdl="WebContent/WEB-INF/wsdls/NezService.wsdl"
        destImplDir="src" 
        destJwsDir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" 
        packageName="server.nez.webservice.service"
        srcPortName="NezSoapPort"
        type="JAXWS">
    </wsdlc>
</target>

<target name="build_nezp">
    <wsdlc
        failOnError="true"
        srcWsdl="WebContent/WEB-INF/wsdls/NezpService.wsdl"
        destImplDir="src" 
        destJwsDir="WebContent/WEB-INF/lib" 
        packageName="server.nezp.webservice.service"
        srcPortName="NezPSoapPort"
        type="JAXWS">
    </wsdlc>
</target>
```